# How to fade out audio of JS-created Audio object?

Tags: javascript

When I try to run this code, my compiler crashes. I've looked at the other answers to this question on here but they aren't working for me.

```
let audio = {
  sound: {
    train: function() {
      this.train = new Audio(
        "train audio"
      );
      this.train.play();
    },
fadeOut: function(sound) {
    while (sound.volume > 0) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        sound.volume - 0.1;
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

fadeOut(audio.sound.train);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a comment but I was unable to comment due to less reputation

Your code is missing } bracket and semicolon at the end of audio

```
let audio = {
  sound: {
    train: function() {
      this.train = new Audio(
        "train audio"
      );
      this.train.play();
    },
fadeOut: function(sound) {
    while (sound.volume > 0) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        sound.volume - 0.1;
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
//Here It was missing
};
//And why are you calling it here 
fadeOut(audio.sound.train);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering only about the debugging part.

Since what could change `sound.volume` will only be called in one second, your while loop will never end, crashing your browser before all this scheduled 
callbacks could ever fire.

Instead you could rewrite this as recursive function:

```
function fadeOut(sound) {
  if( sound.volume > 0 ) { // only if we're not yet at 0
    setTimeout(function() {
      sound.volume -= 0.1;
      fadeOut( sound ); // do it again after one second
    }, 1000);
  }
}

fadeOut( audio.sound.train );
```

But note that decreasing by 0.1 every second can hardly be called a fade-out.

Maybe you should have a look at the Web-Audio-API which provides [convenient methods to fade audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam#Methods).

Comment: Had to change it to "sound.volume -= 0.1", but otherwise that worked.